Callbacks Not Being Registered Correctly in Custom Python GUI Framework Using PyWebView
Question:
I'm building a custom GUI framework in Python using PyWebView. The framework allows defining widgets and handling callbacks for button presses. However, I'm facing issues with registering and invoking callbacks. The callbacks dictionary remains empty, and the callbacks are not being executed.
Here is the core code for the framework:
# core.py
import os
import webview
from framework.api import Api

class Framework:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api = Api()
        self.root_widget = None
        self.window = None

    def register_callback(self, event_name, callback):
        self.api.register_callback(event_name, callback)

    def set_root(self, widget):
        self.root_widget = widget
        self.collect_callbacks(widget)
        if self.window:
            self.update_content()

    def collect_callbacks(self, widget):
        widget_classes = [ElevatedButton, IconButton, TextButton]  # Extend this list as needed
        for widget_class in widget_classes:
            for attribute in dir(widget_class):
                if attribute.startswith('on') and attribute.endswith('ed'):
                    self._collect_callbacks_recursive(widget, attribute)

    def _collect_callbacks_recursive(self, widget, attribute):
        if hasattr(widget, attribute) and getattr(widget, attribute):
            callback = getattr(widget, attribute)
            callback_name = callback.__name__  # Get the name of the callback function
            self.register_callback(callback_name, callback)
            setattr(widget, attribute, callback_name)  # Store the callback name as a string

        if hasattr(widget, 'children'):
            for child in widget.children:
                self._collect_callbacks_recursive(child, attribute)
        elif hasattr(widget, 'child'):
            self._collect_callbacks_recursive(widget.child, attribute)

    def run(self, title):
        if not self.root_widget:
            raise ValueError("Root widget not set. Use set_root() to define the root widget.")

        # Generate HTML content
        html_content = self.root_widget.to_html()
        html_file = 'web/index.html'
        
        # Ensure the web directory exists
        os.makedirs('web', exist_ok=True)

        # Write HTML content to file
        with open(html_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(f"""
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <script src="main.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                {html_content}
            </body>
            </html>
            """)

        # Start PyWebView
        self.window = webview.create_window(title, html_file, js_api=self.api)
        webview.start(debug=True)

    def update_content(self):
        if self.window:
            html_content = self.root_widget.to_html()
            script = f'document.body.innerHTML = `{html_content}`;'
            self.window.evaluate_js(script)

Here is the Api class:
# api.py
class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = {}

    def register_callback(self, name, callback):
        self.callbacks[name] = callback
        print(f"Registered callback: {name}")  # Debugging print

    def on_pressed(self, callback_name):
        print(f"Attempting to invoke callback: {callback_name}")  # Debugging print
        if callback_name in self.callbacks:
            self.callbacks[callback_name]()
            return f"Callback {callback_name} executed"
        else:
            return f"Callback {callback_name} not found"

Here is an example application:
# main.py
from framework.core import Framework
from framework.widgets import Container, Column, Text, ElevatedButton, ListView, IconButton, Icon
from framework.styles import EdgeInsets, ButtonStyle, Colors, TextStyle

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.framework = Framework()
        self.count = 0

    def increment_count(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.framework.set_root(self.build_ui())

    def decrement_count(self):
        self.count -= 1
        self.framework.set_root(self.build_ui())

    def build_ui(self):
        increment_style = ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor='blue',
            foregroundColor='white',
            padding=EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal=10, vertical=10),
            textStyle=TextStyle(fontSize=18)
        )

        decrement_style = ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor='red',
            foregroundColor='white',
            padding=EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal=10, vertical=10),
            textStyle=TextStyle(fontSize=18)
        )

        return Container(
            Column(
                children=[
                    Text(f"Button pressed {self.count} times"),
                    ListView(
                        children=[
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed=self.increment_count,
                                child=Text("Increment"),
                                style=increment_style
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed=self.decrement_count,
                                child=Text("Decrement"),
                                style=decrement_style
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed=self.increment_count,
                                child=Icon(icon_name='plus', size=24, color='white'),
                                style=increment_style
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed=self.decrement_count,
                                child=Icon(icon_name='minus', size=24, color='white'),
                                style=decrement_style
                            )
                        ],
                        padding=EdgeInsets.all(10)
                    )
                ]
            )
        )

    def run(self):
        self.framework.set_root(self.build_ui())
        self.framework.run(title='Button App')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()

The issue is that the callbacks dictionary remains empty, and the callbacks are not being executed. I added debugging prints to trace the registration and invocation of callbacks, but they are not showing the expected output.
What am I missing in the registration and invocation of callbacks? How can I ensure that all callbacks are correctly registered and executed, regardless of their depth in the widget hierarchy?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

if you have debugging info share it with your expected result

on a side note: i don't think that "collecting" callbacks based on some loose naming convention (starts with 'on' ends with 'ed', you don't even check for the type) is a good idea. it's safer to make a huge list but stay in control and be able to call your methods like you want
